# Editing index.php

Tags: magento-1.7

I am having an issue with editing my index.php.  I have opened Firefox and gone into Page Source and I can see the section  that I want to edit, but I cannot find the file within FTP.  The section is within my footer.  Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the [template path hints](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints) and you should see the template file that contains the code you need to change.

Comment: My site is http://www.montechcentral.com.au/index.php/.  I am trying to change the text within the Location Services within the Footer section.  I have even checked within the database.